# Jersey @FormParam string encoding with x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, encoding, jersey

I have a Jersey 2.22 rest web service and one of my endpoint has the following signature:

```
@POST
@Path("/query")
public Response doQuery(@FormParam("query") String query) { ... }
```

I am calling this web service using PostMan passing no particular headers and in the post request and I am passing the "query" form param as "x-www-form-urlencoded".

The jersey application is hosted by a Tomcat 7 that is started with JVM encoding UTF-8, file.encoding UTF-8 and has the URIEncoding of the connector set to UTF-8 too.

If the string sent via PostMan is "<query>è</query>", when running the code in debug I can see that the "è" character is interpreted by Jersey with a bad encoding and my query is not properly executed.

Everything works fine if I add at the beginning of my method something like:

```
String query2 = new String(query.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

I looked at the Forms specs for encoding and I have seen that for decoding the request the client should send an hidden param called "*charset*" that will override the default (US ASCII), however I tried adding this value both as header and as another entry in the x-www-form-urlencoded parameters but Jersey seems to ignore them.

For the moment it's fine also to use the workaround above, but I want to be sure that this will always work fine with Jersey, however I would prefer to have a safer way that is basically letting Jersey interpret the encoding properly from the beginning, even if this includes forcing the client to call my service in a different way (as long as it means adding headers or other parameters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to pass the header "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset-utf-8", which I did try with PostMan but I discovered that, basically, PostMan is ignoring the header content-type when using the post method and selecting already the "x-www-form-urlencoded" radio button option.

Using cUrl with

`-H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"`

did the job.